# Ruby on Rails - production installation without internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I need to get Ruby on Rails (3.0.9) installed onto a production server that doesn't have internet access.  Ruby itself is already installed, and is the same version as on my development machine.  But there are no gems installed at the moment.

Running `gem list -d` on my development machine, I can see a pile of gems installed at `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems`

Basically, I am wondering whether it is possible so simply tar up the gems directory on the development machine, copy to production, and unpack it into the corresponding directory.  I would simply try it and see if it works, but I'm aware this is a production install, and I'd rather not be left with something that looks like it works, but doesn't quite.

Is there a better option?  e.g. copy these files to somewhere else that I set up as a gem repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler offers this feature with [bundle package](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-package.1.html).

Note that this doesn't include gems with sources included via `:git` or `:path` options.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see this feature - I'm just having a go now

Comment: Looks like this is working, except I have to manually get the bundler gem itself across to the target first!

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to run a Rails app you have to have Bundler and Rubygems installed. Thankfully the latter is included in most Ruby builds now. You can probably (hopefully) copy Bundler over manually sans issue.

Comment: For info, what seemed to work was copying the .gem file manually, and running gem install --local bundler.  Now got everything running properly